# Can I configure VS Code to have multiple instances like working different projects?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I configure VS Code to have multiple instances like working on different projects with different set of extensions used for each?

e.g. I want one instance with a few extensions, other with some other extensions, and third with no extensions, etc.

P.S.
I don't want to enable/disable extensions and configurations manually.

Kindly suggest a solution to this problem or an automated way of doing this.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but maybe that is possible with their config file? Maybe it is possible to enable/disable extensions through there.

Comment: you can disable extensions on workspace level, go to the extension page in the Extension Bar